# Understand the processed state in the BFS implementation of the Algorithm Design Manual (Second Edition)

Tags: c, algorithm, graph-theory, breadth-first-search

In the notes to the implementation of BFS, the book says "A vertex is considered processed after we have traversed all outgoing edges from it", which is contradict to the given implementation:

```
bfs(graph *g, int start)
{
  queue q;
  int v;
  inv y;
  edgenode *p;

  init_queue(&q);
  enqueue(&q, start);
  discovered[start] = TRUE;

  while (empty_queue(&q) == FALSE)
    {
      v = dequeue(y);
      processed[v] = TRUE;
      p = g->edges[v];
      while (p != NULL)
        {
          y = p->y;
          if ((process[y] == FALSE) || g->undirected)
            {
              process_edge(v, y);
            }
          if (discovered[y] == FALSE)
            {
              enqueue(&q, y);
              discovered[y] = TRUE;
              parent[y] = v;
            }
          p = p->next;
        }
    }
}
```

Shouldn't the `processed[v] = TRUE;` be placed after the while loop?

Answer (score 0):

In the context of this implementation, if the graph has self-loops, it will process edge (v, v) for some v. Of course, we can move the `processed[v] = TRUE;`, after the while loop, but in this case we should carefully treat self-loops(resulting in more code).

Comment: please improve your answer.